# How do I remove the last 5, or more, or less characters in a textbox for vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, text, box

Example: say i have a text box that has the text "visual basic" is there a way i can remove "basic" or even if i don't know the text is there a way i can remove the last 5 or more or less in the text box?

Comment: what does `remove the last 5 or more or less in the text box` mean? Is this a varying number, and what causes it be more or less?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyString = TextBox1.Text
TextBox1.Text = MyString.Left(MyString.Length - 5)
```

If `Left` doesn't work, try this:

```
MyString = TextBox1.Text
If MyString.Length < 5 Then
    TextBox1.Text = MyString.SubString(5, str.Length - 5)
End If
```

Comment: @user7777777, the logic in the if statement is backwards.

Comment: @OneFineDay: So it should be `MyString.Length < 5`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want remove last word

```
Dim words AS String() = YourTextBox.Text.Split(" "c)
YourTextBox.Text = String.Join(" ", words.Take(words - 1))
```

If you want remove some number of last characters

```
Dim amountToRemove As Integer = 5
YoutTextBox.Text = YoutTextBox.Text.Remove(YoutTextBox.Text.Length - amountToRemove)
```

Or LINQ approach

```
Dim amountOfCharactersToRemove As Integer = 5
Dim amountOfCharactersToTake = YourTextBox.Text.Length - amountOfCharactersToRemove 
Dim characters As Char() = YourTextBox.Text.
                                       ToCharArray().
                                       Take(amountOfCharactersToTake).
                                       ToArray()
YoutTextBox.Text = new string(characters)
```